# Can't give API reference in Digital persona project

Tags: java, fingerprint, digital-persona-sdk

I am first time working on Digital Persona project. But can't give references in it like:

```
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.*;
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.ui.swing.DPFPCapture;
```

for using :

```
 DPFPCapture capture=DPFPGlobal.getCaptureFactory().createCapture();
```

I think I have kept the project at wrong place. Then where should I keep the project?

Comment: You need to import the library for digital persona before you can use it in your code. So what IDE are you using to make your application? Check some of these other questions for answers: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+import+a+library

Comment: @sorified I am using Netbeans and yeah I imported libraries and that worked for me... :) Thank you for your response...